# Linear Transformations in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

We are given:

Show how to evaluate a linear transformation for a specific vector $x$ , when the transformation is defined in the form $$T(x) = y$$

We know that a linear transformation is defined as

$$T:\mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$$

if there exists a real matrix $$ A = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    a_{11} & ... & a_{1n}\\
    ... & ... & ...\\
    a_{m1} & ... & a_{mn}
    \end{array}\right]
$$

Such that for every $x = (x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R^n}$ we have $T(x_1, ..., x_n) = (y_1, ..., y_m)$ where

$$ y_1 = a_{11}x_1 + ... + a_{1n}x_n, $$
$$ ... $$
$$ y_m = a_{m1}x_1 + ... + a_{mn}x_n$$

But im confused and I don't know if this will fully answer the question.

Comment: Put the 11 inside a pair of { }. Also, you need to be more specific, and it's not a good habit thinking of linear transformations as a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the x column vector with the given matrix.